# Trim first and last labels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I've got a plot that is tabulating two types of data by day and I'm looking to just trim the first and last label from the plot. Here is a reproducible example of the data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
dates <- paste0("2014-01-", 1:31)
dat <- data.frame("Date" = sample(dates, 4918, replace=T), 
                  "Type" = sample(c('Type1', 'Type2'), 4918, replace=T, probs=c(.55, .45)))

p.data <- dat %>% group_by(Date, Type) %>% summarise(Freq = n())
p.data$Date <- as.Date(p.data$Date)
```

Here is the code for the plot:

```
p <- ggplot(data=p.data, aes(x=Date, y=Freq, fill=Type)) + 
              geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge') +
              labs(x='Date', y='Count', title='Frequency of Data by Day') + 
              theme_bw() + 
              theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90),
                    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                    plot.title = element_text(vjust=1.4),
                    legend.position='bottom') + 
              scale_x_date(labels=date_format("%a %d"), 
                           breaks=date_breaks("day"), 
                           limits=c(as.Date('2014-01-01'), as.Date('2014-01-31'))) + 
              scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 150), breaks=seq(from=0, to=150, by=25)) + 
              scale_fill_manual(values=c('dark grey', 'light green'))
```

As you can see, there are two label points for the day prior to the beginning of the month and the day after the last day of the month. How do I trim those off? Can I just subset the labels and breaks call in `scale_x_date()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `expand` argument in `scale_x_date` is one way to do it. It tries to be helpful by making some extra space around the edges, but in this case it adds more than a day, so the axis labels have those extra days.

```
p <- ggplot(data=p.data, aes(x=Date, y=Freq, fill=Type)) + 
              geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge') +
              labs(x='Date', y='Count', title='Frequency of Data by Day') + 
              theme_bw() + 
              theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90),
                    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                    plot.title = element_text(vjust=1.4),
                    legend.position='bottom') + 
              scale_x_date(labels=date_format("%a %d"), 
                           breaks=date_breaks("day"), 
                           limits=c(as.Date('2014-01-01'), as.Date('2014-01-31')),
                           expand=c(0, .9)) + 
              scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 150), breaks=seq(from=0, to=150, by=25)) + 
              scale_fill_manual(values=c('dark grey', 'light green'))
```