# Labels in ggplot2 point labels and Breaks

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have recently started using `ggplot2`, and I am depending on help manual to understand how `ggplot2` works.

**Objective:** Customize tick marks in graph.

**a) x-axis**

Here's what I did:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 3, 5) * 1000, y = 1)
 axs <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
   geom_point() +
   labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)
 axs
 axs + scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1000,3000, 5000), labels = c("1k","3k","5k")) #works
```

This works well, but I wanted to print zero as well. So, here's what I did:

```
axs + scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0,1000,3000, 5000), labels = c("0","1k","3k","5k")) 
#works but doesn't show zero.
```

I wasn't sure, so I thought of printing even numbers.

```
axs + scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0,2000,4000, 6000), labels = c("0","2k","4k","6k")) 
#doesn't work at all.
```

This shows 2k and 4k, but not 0 and 6k. I am not sure why.

**b) y-axis**
I did similar thing for y-axis without any success.

```
windows()
 t1<-c(0,1,2,3)
 axs + scale_y_continuous(breaks = t1, labels = c("0","1","2","3")) #doesn't work.
```

This only prints "1" and I don't see other points at all. I am not sure why.

I looked at another thread on SO: [Trim first and last labels in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100326/trim-first-and-last-labels-in-ggplot2) However, this thread seems to be focused on printing date format.

Can someone please help me? I am a beginner, so this question might sound too naive for some of you. I am sorry for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the limits of the plot, so try

```
axs + scale_x_continuous(limit = c(0,5000), 
                         breaks = c(0,1000,3000, 5000), 
                         labels = c("0","1k","3k","5k"))
```

Same thing with the y-axis

```
axs + scale_y_continuous(limit = c(0,3),
                         breaks = t1,
                         labels = c("0","1","2","3"))
```